# Processing xsd files having imported namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to achieve this:

Build an xsd file called "hardware" having certain element called "cpu" of a certain namespace called as "dell", but I have to import another namespace in any case called "hp", and hp.xsd is also importing dell.xsd. 
My question is, can I create hardware.xsd by just importing hp.xsd (this will inturn import dell.xsd) which is what I need to access dell:cpu.

Can I do this:
         In hardware.xsd, just import hp.xsd

Instead of:
        hardware.xsd => import dell.xsd and import hp.xsd

My target name space would be "hardware".

Will it help in accessing dell:cpu from hardware by just importing only hp.xsd since hp.xsd is anyway importing dell.xsd???

Comment: I rarely get a quick answer, either I am asking too dumb questions or not explaining well.

Comment: You're failing to include concrete code/XML/XSDs in the form of a ***[mcve]***.  Nobody wants to interpret your natural language interpretation of your missing code; show your code (but in MCVE form).